# Swagger Nginx flask-restplus

Tags: nginx, flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I'm trying to get the Swagger UI from Flask-RESTplus working on a server using Nginx as a proxy.

Swagger served on /api and works locally using http://localhost:5000/api . I'm trying to setup the Nginx as a proxy so I can go to http://ServerIP/api and see the Swagger UI.

I've tried many configurations for Nginx and currently have

```
location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

However, I just see a blank page when going to http://ServerIP/api.  In the Chrome dev tools there is an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
at window.onload (api:75)
```

which refers to:

```
<script src="/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        const ui = window.ui = new SwaggerUIBundle({
```

But I am able to get to (200 OK, serves up the javascript files)
http://ServerIP/swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js http://ServerIP/swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question: [Server response gets cut off half way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557927/server-response-gets-cut-off-half-way-through#12887972)

Nginx needs to have permissions to write to a temp folder when sending large upstream files. Usually you'll see it in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` like

```
2018/06/28 16:34:48 [crit] ... open() "<tmp folder>/x/y/00000000z" failed (13:
Permission denied) while reading upstream, <request info...>
```

to fix this you chown to nginx:nginx (unless you've changed the user manually) eg `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx`. if the permissions aren't at least 7xx you may have to change that but that shouldn't be an issue.

alternatively you can set `proxy_buffering off;` but that isn't recommended if you expect the connections to be longer than usual (speed or size).